# Unable to obtain code for teams: API access is not supported on this channel

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams, api

I am trying to query information about my private team, but I have issues obtaining a code. I did:

Registered an app:

```
Name = stackoverflow.com/c/{team}
OAuth domain = stackoverflow.com
Application web site = https://stackoverflow.com/c/{team}
```

When I navigate to

```
https://stackoverflow.com/oauth?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri=https://stackoverflow.com&scope=no_expiry,access_team|stackoverflow.com/c/{team}
```

I get `API access is not supported on this channel`. What am I missing?

Comment: [API access only available on Basic & Business tier](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4385859-stack-overflow-for-teams-api). Is your Teams on that tier?

Comment: I see. No, it is on the free tier (for now). Maybe the documentation on the API should be updated to state this https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Andrew T. wrote in a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412627/unable-to-obtain-code-for-teams-api-access-is-not-supported-on-this-channel/412630#comment876020_412627), API access is only available on the Basic and Business tiers.

I am using the Free tier (for now), so API access is not supported. The error message is correct.

This is mentioned in [the documentation for Teams](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4385859-stack-overflow-for-teams-api), but it is not mentioned in [the documentation for the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/teams).